# Testing websites for Edge with a Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-edge

I noticed that you can now download Edge on a Mac
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?form=MI13F4&OCID=MI13F4

This is great news as i can now test our websites on Edge browser, but wondering if Edge on Mac will render stuff differently than Edge on Windows?

Comment: You can only know that if you test it on Edge Mac. From [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/05/20/microsoft-edge-macos-canary-preview/), it seems that there will be little difference on fonts, menus, keyboard shortcuts and something else to make it match macOS conventions. I think most of them will be the same.

Comment: Thanks and i can mark this as the answer if you want to add it to the answer section

Comment: Thanks. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only know that if you test it on Edge Mac. From [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/05/20/microsoft-edge-macos-canary-preview/), it seems that there will be little difference on fonts, menus, keyboard shortcuts and something else to make it match macOS conventions. I think most of them will be the same.